# Соединение двух проектов с расширением .py

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, ui, qt-designer

Создаю приложение и решил его делать частями, то есть одна часть приложения в одном коде, другая часть приложения в другом.

Первый файл является главным, второй файл - файлом, который нужно вставить в первый. 
Проблема в том, что второй файл делался с помощью *Qt Designer* и имеет отсылки к **.ui** файлам, не знаю как это правильно соединить.

Вот главный код, в который надо вставить другой код (в 2 страницу):

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt



class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        #размер основного окн
        self.resize(845, 535)
        self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(845, 535))
        self.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(845, 535))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);")        
        #центральный виджет
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.Content = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.Content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        
        self.Content.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Content.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Content.setObjectName("Content")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Content)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        #виджет слева
        self.frame_left_menu = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_left_menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45, 0))
       
        self.frame_left_menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px solid; ")
        
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_left_menu.setObjectName("frame_left_menu")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        #не совсем понял зачем
        self.frame_top_menus = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_top_menus.setObjectName("frame_top_menus")
        #указываем вертикальное выравнивание
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(10)
        self.verticalLayout_1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_1.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.verticalLayout_1.setSpacing(5)
        #домик                                  
        self.btn_page_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_1.setIcon(QIcon('дом.png'))
        self.btn_page_1.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))

        self.btn_page_1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border: 0px solid;}")
        self.btn_page_1.setObjectName("btn_page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_1)
        #Заметки
        self.btn_page_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_2.setIcon(QIcon('заметка1.png'))
        self.btn_page_2.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border: 0px solid;}")
        self.btn_page_2.setObjectName("btn_page_2")
       
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_2)

        #погода
        self.btn_page_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_3.setIcon(QIcon('солнышко.png'))
        self.btn_page_3.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border: 0px solid;}")


        self.btn_page_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('', self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_4.setIcon(QIcon('папочка.png'))                          
        self.btn_page_4.setIconSize(QSize(45, 45))
        self.btn_page_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border: 0px solid;")

        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        timer.start(1000)

        font1 = QFont('Century Gothic', 13, QFont.Bold)
        self.timewidget = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.timewidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45,45))
        self.timewidget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.timewidget.setFont(font1)

        self.btn_page_3.setObjectName("btn_page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_3)
        
        
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_top_menus, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_left_menu)

  
       self.verticalLayout_1.addWidget(self.btn_page_4)                 
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_4)                      

        self.frame_pages = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_pages.setObjectName("frame_pages")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_pages)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800,535))

        self.stackedWidget.setStyleSheet('QStackedWidget{\n'
            'border: 0px solid;')
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        #1 страница
        self.page_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_1.setObjectName("page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_1)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        #указываем что будет находится на 1 странице
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel( self.page_1)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label_1.setFont(font)
        
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_1)
        #2 страница
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_2)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        #указываем что будет находиться в 2 странице
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Страница2", self.page_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF; background-color: #1eae98;")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        #3 страница
        self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_3)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        #указываем что будет находиться на 3 странице
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Страница3", self.page_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(0)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: green; background-color: black;")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.label)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_3)


        self.page_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_4.setObjectName('page_4')
        self.verticalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus) 
        self.verticalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_4)               
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.page_4)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setObjectName('verticalLayout_9')
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Страница4', self.page_4)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(0)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet('color: black; background-color: white;')
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName('label_3')
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_4)


        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
       
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)

        #Нажатие на дом
        self.btn_page_1.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_1))
        #Нажатие на заметки
        self.btn_page_2.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_2))
        #Нажатие на погоду
        self.btn_page_3.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_3))
            

        self.btn_page_4.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_4))

        self.frame_left_menu.installEventFilter(self)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.timewidget, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)

   
#календарь
  
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_1)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet('selection-color: rgb(45, 86, 100)')
        
        
        
        self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.page_1)
        self.calendarWidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 154, 800, 381))
        self.calendarWidget.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 381))
        
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setFont(font)
        self.calendarWidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        
        self.calendarWidget.setGridVisible(False)
        
        self.calendarWidget.setVerticalHeaderFormat(QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.NoVerticalHeader)
        self.calendarWidget.setDateEditEnabled(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setDateEditAcceptDelay(0)
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
        
        self.calendarWidget.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)

    def showTime(self):
        current_time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        label_time = current_time.toString('hh:mm')
        self.timewidget.setText(label_time)



        
        

       

    

StyleSheet = '''
/* Верхняя область навигации                            */
#qt_calendar_navigationbar {
    background-color: rgb(0, 188, 212);
    min-width: 800px;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-height: 35px;
    max-height: 35px;



}

/*  Кнопка последнего месяца и кнопка следующего месяца */
       
#qt_calendar_prevmonth, #qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    border: none;                     /* убрать границу */
    margin-top: 0px;
    color: white;
    min-width: 30px;
    max-width: 30px;
    min-height: 30px;
    max-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;            /* выглядит как эллипс */
    font-weight: bold;              /* шрифт полужирный    */
    
   
    qproperty-icon: none;    
    background-color: transparent; /* Цвет фона прозрачный */
}

#qt_calendar_prevmonth {
    qproperty-text: "<";         /* Изменить текст кнопки  */
}

#qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    qproperty-text: ">";
}

#qt_calendar_prevmonth:hover, #qt_calendar_nextmonth:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 100);
}

#qt_calendar_prevmonth:pressed, #qt_calendar_nextmonth:pressed {
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 100);
}

/*  год, месяц                                                */
#qt_calendar_yearbutton, #qt_calendar_monthbutton {
    color: white;
    margin: -1px;
    min-width: -1px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 188, 212, 100)

}
#qt_calendar_yearbutton:hover, #qt_calendar_monthbutton:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 100);
}
#qt_calendar_yearbutton:pressed, #qt_calendar_monthbutton:pressed {
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 100);
}

/* Поле ввода года                                                        */
#qt_calendar_yearedit {
    min-width: 85px;
    color: white;
    background: transparent;         /* Сделать фон окна ввода прозрачным */
}
#qt_calendar_yearedit::up-button {   /* Кнопка вверх                      */
    width: 25px;
    subcontrol-position: right;      
}
#qt_calendar_yearedit::down-button { /* Кнопка вниз     */
    width: 25px;
    subcontrol-position: left;       
}

/* меню выбора месяца                                          */
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu {
     background-color: white;

    
    
}



CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu_item {
    padding: 10px;


   
}
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu_item_selected_enabled {
    background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    selection-color: rgb(45, 86, 100);
    selection-background-color: rgb(205, 217, 226);

    
}
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_menu-indicator {

    subcontrol-position: right center;                
}

/* ниже календарной формы */
#qt_calendar_calendarview {
    outline: 0px;                                 /* Удалить выделенную пунктирную рамку */
    selection-background-color: rgb(0, 188, 212); 
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12,))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Вот код, который надо вставить:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, QtTest
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
import weather
import time
import datetime
from weather import DAYS 

#два класса с числами Фобаначе , для правного визуала 
H_show = [
    155,156,157,158,
    160,168,181,202,
    236,291,380,400,
    440,500,535,
]
H_hide = [
    155,156,157,158,
    160,168,181,202,
    236,291,380,400,
    440,500,535,
]

class WeatherData(QThread):
    req = weather.today()
    temp = req['temp']
    feels = req['feels']
    pres = req['pressure']
    speed = str(req['wind']['speed'])
    city = req['city']
    type = req['dis']


    week = weather.week()



    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)


    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                req = weather.today()
            except:
                req['temp'] = self.temp
                req['feels'] = self.feels
                req['pressure'] = self.pres
                req['wind']['speed'] = self.pres
                req['city'] = self.city
                req['dis'] = self.type

            try:
                req_week = weather.week()
                self.week = req_week
            except:
                self.week = DAYS

            self.temp = req['temp']
            self.feels = req['feels']
            self.pres = req['pressure']
            self.speed = str(req['wind']['speed'])
            self.city = req['city']
            self.type = req['dis']
            time.sleep(600)






class App(QWidget):
    #
    #
    #
    #
    #
    #
    #
    show_more = True 

    def __init__(self, app):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.weather = WeatherData()
        self.weather.start()
        self.app = app
        self.set()
        self.setData()
        self.setMore()



    def set(self):
        self.w_root = uic.loadUi('root.ui')
        self.w_root.installEventFilter(self)
        self.w_root.btn_more.clicked.connect(self.setHeight)
        self.w_root.show()
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
# перемещение кнопки с ресайзом
    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        self.w_root.resize(444, self.w_root.height())
        self.w_root.btn_more.move(0, self.w_root.height()-26)
        self.w_root.l_day.move(8, self.w_root.height()-18)
        self.app.processEvents()
        return False
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#

#устанавливаем значение на сегодня
    def setData(self):
        # данные погоды
        self.w_root.l_temp.setText(str(self.weather.temp) + '°C')
        self.w_root.l_fell.setText(self.weather.feels)
        self.w_root.l_pres.setText(self.weather.pres)
        self.w_root.l_wind.setText(self.weather.speed + 'м/с')
        self.w_root.l_city.setText(self.weather.city)
        self.w_root.l_type.setText(self.weather.type)

        #иконка погоды
        px_logo = QPixmap(f'C:/python/pogoda/{self.weather.type}.png')
        self.w_root.l_logo.setPixmap(px_logo)

        #день недели
        today = DAYS[datetime.datetime.today().weekday()]
        self.w_root.l_day.setText(today['title'])
        color = today['color']
        self.w_root.l_day.setStyleSheet(f'color:{color}')



#
#
#
#
#

    def setHeight(self):
        if self.w_root.height() >= 200:
            self.show_more = False
        if self.show_more:
            for i in H_hide:
                if self.w_root.height() > i:
                    continue
                self.w_root.resize(444, i)
                self.w_root.btn_more.move(0, i-26)
                self.w_root.l_day.move(8,i-18)
                self.app.processEvents()
                time.sleep(.02)
            self.show_more = False
        else:
            for i in reversed(H_show):
                self.w_root.resize(444, i)
                self.w_root.btn_more.move(0, i-26)
                self.w_root.l_day.move(8,i-18)
                self.app.processEvents()
                time.sleep(.02)
            self.show_more = True
        App.show_more = self.show_more
#
#
#
#
#
#
#



    def setMore(self):
        for i in self.weather.week:
            w_day = uic.loadUi('day.ui')
            w_day.setObjectName('w_day_' + str(i['num']))
            w_day.l_title.setText(i['title'])
            w_day.l_temp.setText(str(round(i['temp'])) + '°C')
            w_day.l_type.setText(i['type'])
            w_day.l_title.setStyleSheet('color: ' + i['color'] + '; background-color: none; border: none')
            if i['active']:
                w_day.setStyleSheet('border: 1px solid' + i['color'])
            else:
                w_day.setStyleSheet('border: none')
            self.w_root.box.addWidget(w_day)
        self.w_root.box.addStretch()







if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    ex = App(app)
    app.exec_()
```

Вот ссылка на диск с .ui файлами [Яндекс Диск](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/J5qWebydOkgKLA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Позволю дать вам некоторые советы:

- хотя ваш вопрос звучит как: 'Соединение двух проектов с расширением .py',
  я понял что вам надо вставить виджет `App` из втогого файла
  как страницу (например четвертую) в основное приложение **`main.py`**.
- ваше основное приложение **`main.py`** - содержало много ошибок.
  Я исправил их, смотрите по тексту кода.
- **НЕТ проблемы** в том, что второй файл делался с помощью *Qt Designer*
  и имеет отсылки к **.ui** файлам.
- я не могу проверить правильно ли работает ваш второй файл,
  поэтому я заменил его каким-то своим **q1297974_second.py**.
- предположим, что ваш второй файл рабочий, но некоторые вещи вам надо в нем подправить.

1. Не надо передавать `app` - **`ex = App(app)`**
2. замените

.

```
... 
def __init__(self, app):
    QWidget.__init__(self)
...
```

на

```
... 
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
...
```

3. уберите все строки, в которых есть `self.app`
4. замените все `self.app.processEvents()` на `QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()`

- в основном файле:

1. делаем импорт **`from q1297974_second import App`**
2. создаем экземпляр **`self.second = App()`**
3. добавляем в layout - **`self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.second)`**

- ВСЕ.

**q1297974_main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from q1297974_second import App                              # +++ 


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        #размер основного окн
        self.resize(845, 535)
#        self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(845, 535))
#        self.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(845, 535))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(245, 45, 45);")        
        #центральный виджет
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
# Content horizontalLayout_2 
        self.Content = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.Content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        
        self.Content.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Content.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Content.setObjectName("Content")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Content)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        #виджет слева
        self.frame_left_menu = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_left_menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45, 0))
       
        self.frame_left_menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px solid; ")
        
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_left_menu.setObjectName("frame_left_menu")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        
# frame_top_menus - verticalLayout_4 от  frame_left_menu
        self.frame_top_menus = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_top_menus.setObjectName("frame_top_menus")
        #указываем вертикальное выравнивание
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(10)

# ?  verticalLayout_1
        '''      
        self.verticalLayout_1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_1.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.verticalLayout_1.setSpacing(5)
        '''
        
        #домик                                  
        self.btn_page_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_1.setIcon(QIcon('Ok.png'))
        self.btn_page_1.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
# ?
# ?        self.btn_page_1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border: 0px solid;}")
        self.btn_page_1.setStyleSheet('border: 0px solid red;')
                
        self.btn_page_1.setObjectName("btn_page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_1)
        #Заметки
        self.btn_page_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_2.setIcon(QIcon('im.png'))
        self.btn_page_2.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
#        self.btn_page_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border: 0px solid;}")
        self.btn_page_2.setStyleSheet('border: 0px solid red;')
        self.btn_page_2.setObjectName("btn_page_2")
       
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_2)

        #погода
        self.btn_page_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("", self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_3.setIcon(QIcon('ball.png'))
        self.btn_page_3.setIconSize(QSize(45,45))
        self.btn_page_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
#        self.btn_page_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border: 0px solid;}")


        self.btn_page_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('', self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_4.setIcon(QIcon('lena.jpg'))                          
        self.btn_page_4.setIconSize(QSize(45, 45))
        self.btn_page_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
#        self.btn_page_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {border: 0px solid;")

        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        timer.start(1000)

        font1 = QFont('Century Gothic', 13, QFont.Bold)
        self.timewidget = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.timewidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(45,45))
        self.timewidget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.timewidget.setFont(font1)

        self.btn_page_3.setObjectName("btn_page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_3)
        
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_top_menus, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_left_menu)

# ?  verticalLayout_1  
# ?        self.verticalLayout_1.addWidget(self.btn_page_4)                 
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_4)                      

        self.frame_pages = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_pages.setObjectName("frame_pages")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_pages)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 535))

# ?        self.stackedWidget.setStyleSheet('QStackedWidget{\n'
# ?            'border: 0px solid;')
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        
#1 страница
        self.page_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_1.setObjectName("page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_1)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        #указываем что будет находится на 1 странице
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Страница 1", self.page_1)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label_1.setFont(font)
        
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_1)
        
        #2 страница
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_2)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        #указываем что будет находиться в 2 странице
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Страница2", self.page_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF; background-color: #1eae98;")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        #3 страница
        self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_3)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        #указываем что будет находиться на 3 странице
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Страница3", self.page_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
# ?        font.setPointSize(0)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: green; background-color: black;")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.label)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_3)

# page_4 verticalLayout_9
        self.page_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_4.setObjectName('page_4')
# ?        
# ?        self.verticalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_4)               
# ?        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.page_4)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setObjectName('verticalLayout_9')

# +++ ^
        self.second = App()
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.second)

        '''
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Страница4', self.page_4)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
# ?        font.setPointSize(0)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(True)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet('color: black; background-color: white;')
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName('label_3')
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.label_3)
        '''
        
        
# +++ ^        
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_4)

        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        
# verticalLayout  centralwidget     
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)    
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
# verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)        
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)

        #Нажатие на дом
        self.btn_page_1.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_1))
        #Нажатие на заметки
        self.btn_page_2.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_2))
        #Нажатие на погоду
        self.btn_page_3.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_3))

        self.btn_page_4.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.page_4))

        self.frame_left_menu.installEventFilter(self)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.timewidget, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)

   
# календарь

# ?     
        '''
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_1)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet('selection-color: rgb(45, 86, 100)')
        '''
        
        
        self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.page_1)
        self.calendarWidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 154, 800, 381))
        self.calendarWidget.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 381))
        
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setKerning(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setFont(font)
        self.calendarWidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        
        self.calendarWidget.setGridVisible(False)
        
        self.calendarWidget.setVerticalHeaderFormat(QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.NoVerticalHeader)
        self.calendarWidget.setDateEditEnabled(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setDateEditAcceptDelay(0)
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
        
        self.calendarWidget.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
# +++        
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.calendarWidget)

    def showTime(self):
        current_time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        label_time = current_time.toString('hh:mm')
        self.timewidget.setText(label_time)
 

StyleSheet = '''
/* Верхняя область навигации                            */
#qt_calendar_navigationbar {
    background-color: rgb(0, 188, 212);
    min-width: 800px;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-height: 35px;
    max-height: 35px;
}

/*  Кнопка последнего месяца и кнопка следующего месяца */
#qt_calendar_prevmonth, #qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    border: none;                     /* убрать границу */
    margin-top: 0px;
    color: white;
    min-width: 30px;
    max-width: 30px;
    min-height: 30px;
    max-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;            /* выглядит как эллипс */
    font-weight: bold;              /* шрифт полужирный    */
    qproperty-icon: none;    
    background-color: transparent; /* Цвет фона прозрачный */
}

#qt_calendar_prevmonth {
    qproperty-text: "<";         /* Изменить текст кнопки  */
}
#qt_calendar_nextmonth {
    qproperty-text: ">";
}
#qt_calendar_prevmonth:hover, #qt_calendar_nextmonth:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 100);
}
#qt_calendar_prevmonth:pressed, #qt_calendar_nextmonth:pressed {
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 100);
}

/*  год, месяц                                                */
#qt_calendar_yearbutton, #qt_calendar_monthbutton {
    color: white;
    margin: -1px;
    min-width: -1px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 188, 212, 100)
}
#qt_calendar_yearbutton:hover, #qt_calendar_monthbutton:hover {
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 100);
}
#qt_calendar_yearbutton:pressed, #qt_calendar_monthbutton:pressed {
    background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 100);
}

/* Поле ввода года                                                        */
#qt_calendar_yearedit {
    min-width: 85px;
    color: white;
    background: transparent;         /* Сделать фон окна ввода прозрачным */
}
#qt_calendar_yearedit::up-button {   /* Кнопка вверх                      */
    width: 25px;
    subcontrol-position: right;      
}
#qt_calendar_yearedit::down-button { /* Кнопка вниз     */
    width: 25px;
    subcontrol-position: left;       
}

/* меню выбора месяца                                          */
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu {
     background-color: white;
}

CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu_item {
    padding: 10px;
}
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_QMenu_item_selected_enabled {
    background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    selection-color: rgb(45, 86, 100);
    selection-background-color: rgb(205, 217, 226);
}
CalendarWidget_QToolButton_menu-indicator {
    subcontrol-position: right center;                
}

/* ниже календарной формы */
#qt_calendar_calendarview {
    outline: 0px;                                 /* Удалить выделенную пунктирную рамку */
    selection-background-color: rgb(0, 188, 212); 
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12,))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1297974_second.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, pyqtProperty
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QApplication, QMainWindow


class AnimationShadowEffect(QGraphicsDropShadowEffect):
    def __init__(self, color, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AnimationShadowEffect, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setColor(color)
        self.setOffset(0, 0)
        self.setBlurRadius(0)
        self._radius = 0
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self)
        self.animation.setTargetObject(self)
        self.animation.setDuration(2000)            
        self.animation.setLoopCount(-1)             
        self.animation.setPropertyName(b'radius')
        self.animation.setKeyValueAt(0, 1)
        self.animation.setKeyValueAt(0.5, 30)
        self.animation.setKeyValueAt(1, 1)

    def start(self):
        self.animation.start()

    def stop(self, r=0):
        self.animation.stop()
        self.radius = r

    @pyqtProperty(int)
    def radius(self):
        return self._radius

    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, r):
        self._radius = r
        self.setBlurRadius(r)
        

class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()

# self.w_root = uic.loadUi('root.ui')
        self.w_root = uic.loadUi("Test_333.ui", self)                                  # +++

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.w_root.centralwidget)   
        self.layout.addWidget(self.w_root.designer_button, 1, 1, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        self.w_root.designer_button.setFixedSize(200, 70)
        self.w_root.designer_button.setCheckable(True)
        self.aniButton = AnimationShadowEffect(QtCore.Qt.white, self.w_root.designer_button)
        self.w_root.designer_button.hover.connect(self.button_hover)   
        self.w_root.designer_button.setGraphicsEffect(self.aniButton)

    def button_hover(self, hover):
        if hover == "enterEvent":
            self.aniButton.start()
        elif hover == "leaveEvent":
            self.aniButton.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Test_333.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>357</width>
    <height>205</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(41, 41, 62);</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="PushButton" name="designer_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>80</x>
      <y>40</y>
      <width>201</width>
      <height>71</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    background-color: rgb(28, 28, 42);
    border: 1px solid rgb(202, 202, 202);
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: rgb(202, 202, 202);
    font-family: Calibre, Helvetica Neue, Segoe UI, Helvetica, Arial, Lucida          Grande sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

QPushButton:hover { 
    background-color: rgb(16, 16, 24);
    color: rgb(76, 76, 76);
}

QPushButton:pressed { 
    background-color: rgb(6, 6, 8);
    color: rgb(41, 41, 62);
}

</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>357</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>PushButton</class>
   <extends>QPushButton</extends>
   <header>my_PushButton</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: по какой причине  **self.app.processEvents()** надо менять на **QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()**

Comment: @Gidra  по той причине, что я предложил убрать все строки, в которых есть `self.app`

Comment: @S.Nick, у меня второй файл запускается в виде нового окна, а не в 4 страничке, хотя я сделал все как вы указали в ответе

Comment: @ivapop задайте новый вопрос, приложите пример, который демонстрирует проблему.